# Unit testing a custom view with only setter methods

Tags: android, unit-testing, user-interface, android-testing

I am writing a custom view class which I would like to unit test, however its only output is the view that is drawn to the Canvas (in the onDraw method). All other methods are setter methods that take input, but provide no meaningful output.

It would seem incredibly tedious to try to match the graphical output with pre-rendered comparison images, but I cannot think of another way to test this custom view. Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Comment: Could you maybe specify what kind of view you are trying to test? If all you do is to draw a circle there is not that much that could be done.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I am wondering about the general case, but one specific example would be a custom progress bar. Another might be a status indicator that changes it's look based on status "online", "away" etc.